# AHK JSON String to Object

Tags: json, autohotkey

I have a Auto Hot Key 2 script, that does a HTTP Post.  I get back a JSON formatted string, and I want to be able to do something with it.

I found a library for the conversion:  https://github.com/cocobelgica/AutoHotkey-JSON

But as soon as I make a AHK v2 script with the below, I get a error.

`#Include JSON.ahk`

Error:
[image]

Even running the Example_JSON.ahk gives the same error.

I am not looking to fix that project as it looks dead.  So my question is what does everyone use for JSON to Object in Auto Hot Key 2+ ?

Comment: Which ahk version are you using? have you tryied to update ahk to the latest version?

Comment: version 2-0-beta.13

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used JSON in AHKv2, but a quick test now tells me that JXON_ahk2 <sup>([GitHub](https://github.com/TheArkive/JXON_ahk2)|([Forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=74799))</sup> seems to work:

```
#Include _JXON.ahk

text := "
(
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
)"

json := jxon_load(&text)
MsgBox(json["glossary"]["title"])
```

Just used to first example JSON from Google.
In the forum post HotkeyIt's Yaml/JSON parser is also mentioned, might be worth taking a look at is as well.